# Автоматический запуск определения местонахождения через gps и google map api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

У меня проект с Google Maps и GPS для Android. Я все сделал: приложение находит свое текущее местоположение. Я хочу усовершенствовать свой проект. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб при включении карт, текущее местоположение находилось сразу? То есть было бы не нужно нажимать на кнопку "искать", а сервис начинал работать сразу при включения карты (естественно интернет и gps на телефоне включены).

Не то что моя кнопка "искать", а такая как в Google Map есть. У меня все очень просто:

```
 googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: А как у вас реализована кнопка "искать"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В onCreate ваше текущее местоположение определяется, и там же обновляете камеру (отправляете ее к текущему местоположению):

```
LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 10));
```